# How to create Oracle RAC database using dbca silent mode with different db_name and db_unique_name

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to use dbca (version 11.2.0.3) silent mode to create a RAC database on a 2-node RAC and the db_name and db_unique_name must be different, I tried following dbca command

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbca -silent -createDatabase -templateName 'General_Purpose.dbc' -adminManaged -emConfiguration NONE -gdbName 'oiddb' -sid 'oiddb' -sysPassword oracle -systemPassword oracle -asmSYSPassword oracle -asmsnmpPassword oracle -storageType ASM -diskGroupName DATA -datafileJarLocation /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/assistants/dbca/templates -nodelist 'node1,node2' -characterset AL32UTF8 -obfuscatedPasswords false -sampleSchema false -oratabLocation /etc/oratab -initParams db_unique_name=oiddbp,processes=7000,db_name=oiddb -listeners LISTENER_OID
```

But it failed at this error

```
DBCA_PROGRESS : 85%
ORA-17502: ksfdcre:4 Failed to create file +DATA/oiddb/spfileoiddb.ora
ORA-15173: entry 'oiddb' does not exist in directory '/'

PRCR-1079 : Failed to start resource ora.oiddbp.db
CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.oiddbp.db start" encountered the following error:
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-01565: error in identifying file '+DATA/oiddb/spfileoiddb.ora'
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +DATA/oiddb/spfileoiddb.ora
ORA-15056: additional error message
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +DATA/oiddb/spfileoiddb.ora
ORA-15173: entry 'oiddb' does not exist in directory '/'
ORA-06512: at line 4
. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/u01/app/11.2.0/grid/log/node1/agent/crsd/oraagent_oracle/oraagent_oracle.log".
```

I was monitoring my ASM during the run and I can see +DATA/oiddbp got created, but it seems that dbca was trying to create the spfile under +DATA/oiddb.

I then tried to create the database with the same parameters using dbca UI mode and it did create +DATA/oiddbp and spfile under it.

I am wondering if this could be an Oracle bug? Any workaround or how to resolve this? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked RAC, please see if you can use this non-RAC example as a starting point.
For db_name != db_unique_name != sid
- Non-RAC
- Oracle 12.1
- Custom Database (not seed)

On the command line, set ddbname == parameter db_unique_name, and also set parameter db_name

```
dbca    \
-silent \
-createDatabase \
-templateName    wailua.dbt     \
-sid wailua20           \
-gdbname wailuaq        \
-initParams db_unique_name=wailuaq,db_name=wailua       \
```

where wailua.dbt is copied from New_Database.dbt

db_name and db_unique_name are not mentioned in wailua.dbt

Note that variables 
SID and DB_UNIQUE_NAME expand in the template.

```
[oracle@waipio1 wailua20 templates]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
wailua20

[oracle@waipio1 wailua20 templates]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jun 11 00:48:22 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> show parameter db_name

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_name                              string      wailua
SQL> show parameter db_unique_name

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_unique_name                       string      wailuaq

oratab:
wailua20:/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1:N:         # line added by Agent

ASM:
asmcmd ls data/WAILUAQ/
CONTROLFILE/
DATAFILE/
ONLINELOG/
PARAMETERFILE/
TEMPFILE/
spfilewailua20.ora
```

Full crdb.wailua.ksh dbca script: http://pastebin.com/vx3k5g3U/

dbca log: http://pastebin.com/8UQDEDZn/